# How to get group of words as Rationale using Natural Language processing/NLTK?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

consider below sentence, I want know how to extract rational from below sentence. Rationale meaning in this context = `single/group of words which gives some meanigful information to sentense`

> I am play hockey.
>
> > **play**
>
> I am feeling cold.
>
> > rational: **feeling cold**
>
> Sam is going to do Master of Science in Stanford next year.
>
> > rational: **Master of Science.**

Those words are mix combination of adverbs, verbs and adjective. So how to extract those in nltk?

I want to know how to extract group of words as rational using nltk ?

Comment: I believe you mean *rationale* not *rational*.

Comment: yes, I mean rationale